# Creating Next and Previous buttons for navigation using mysql result

Tags: php, mysql

I have taken the working code from this thread:
[Creating Next and Previous buttons for navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394058/creating-next-and-previous-buttons-for-navigation)

It works for me but right now I would like to ask is there any way to disable the link if it reaches the 1st or the last ID?

Here's my brief code:

```
function getNavID($id) {

$result4= mysql_query("SELECT 
( SELECT id FROM products_list WHERE id > '$id' LIMIT 1 )
AS nextValue,
( SELECT id FROM products_list WHERE id < '$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 )
AS prevValue
FROM products_list");
if ($resultID = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
    return $resultID;
}
else {
    return NULL;
}
}

$LinkID = getNavID($id);

<p><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($LinkID['prevValue']); ?>">Previous</a></p>
<p><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($LinkID['nextValue']); ?>">Next</a></p>
```

Let's say the page I'm on now is ID=1 so logically, there is no ID lesser than 1. Is there any way that I can do to disable the links if the ID reaches the min and max ID ?

Thanks in advance guys.

Regards,
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ID=1, `$LinkID['prevValue']` should return NULL, which you can check [easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576243/php-check-for-null). Include a check, so that you only print the link if there is a previous/next value, e.g.:

```
<p>
<?php
    if (!is_null($LinkID['prevValue'])) {
>?
    <a href="update.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($LinkID['prevValue']); ?>">Previous</a>
<?php
    } else {
        echo "No previous entries.";
    }
?>
</p>
```

And analogously for Next entry.

By the way, just for completeness' sake, I would rewrite the SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT id FROM products_list
        WHERE id > '$id' LIMIT 1 ) AS nextValue,
    ( SELECT id FROM products_list
        WHERE id < '$id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS prevValue
    FROM products_list
    LIMIT 1
```

I.e. an additional LIMIT 1 at the end. You might not notice a difference in your result, but with your statement, the database delivers one row per entry in the table products_list (of which you only use the first, and they are all equal).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried your code but it's not working. It show me a blank page.

Comment: I think I missed a parenthesis, I will correct that. In such cases (blank page), check the server log (or enable display of errors in browser (display_errors setting in php.ini, but enable that only if you're not on a production system!).